# Quine–McCluskey algorithm in haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I found the Quine–McCluskey algorithm implemented in Haskell, but I don't know what I have to do to load it in GHCi.
Can someone help me out?

http://dilawarnotes.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/quine-mcclusky-algorithm-in-haskell/

https://github.com/dilawar/ee677/tree/master/Assignment01/haskell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [Quine.lhs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dilawar/ee677/master/Assignment01/haskell/Quine.lhs) and [tingu.hs](https://github.com/dilawar/ee677/blob/master/Assignment01/haskell/tingu.hs) and then run `ghci Quine.lhs tingu.hs`. This will load the modules `Quine` and `Main` that you can then use from GHCi.